# batch file one line coding (for loops)

Tags: batch-file

I want to make this:

```
@echo off
for %%x in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do (
    ctext.exe {07} %%x
)
echo.
for %%y in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do (
    ctext.exe {07}%%y
    for %%x in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do (
    ctext.exe {%%x%%y}%%x%%y
    )
    echo.
)
pause>nul
exit /b
```

Into one line but how can I get commands in after the for loop?

```
@echo off && for %%x in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do ( ctext.exe {07} %%x ) <-- Here -->
```

I can not use `&&` because it uses it in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` and `||` are the equivalent to `then` `else` parts of a condition based on the errorlevel of the previous command. So the following

```
echo "test" | find "is" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo not found
) else (
    echo found
)
```

can be written as

```
echo "test" | find "is" >nul && echo found || echo not found
```

What you need to concatenate the commands is `&` and place some parenthesis to ensure separation of for commands

```
(for in () do ( a & b )) & (for in () do ( b & c ))
```

Comment: The code looks like this now: `@echo off && (for %%x in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do ( ctext.exe {07} %%x )) && echo. && (for %%y in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do ( ctext.exe {07}%%y ) && (for %%x in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F) do ( ctext.exe {%%x%%y}%%x%%y )) && echo. ) && pause>nul && exit /b`

Comment: @Silly, change your `&&` with `&`

Comment: @Silly: This is the way I would do that: `@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set h=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F & for %%x in (!h!) do (ctext.exe {07} %%x) & echo. & for %%y in (!h!) do (ctext.exe {07}%%y & for %%x in (!h!) do (ctext.exe {%%x%%y}%%x%%y) & echo.) & pause>nul & exit /b`